# replace words with different values from sentences

Tags: php

I have one sentence like this:

```
{pattern} test {pattern} how r u {pattern}
```

How can I replace `{pattern}` with different values like

```
{AAA} test {BBB} how r u {CCC}
```

Comment: depends on how you want these values to change.

Comment: If the pattern is only one and not `{pattern1}`, `{pattern2}` etc, how do you decide with what to replace the `{pattern}`? When it's `{AAA}`, `{BBB}` or `{CCC}`?

Comment: No specific value we can also do like {BBB} test {AAA} how r u {CCC} or other random values

Comment: @enenen well you could set the pattern in which you modify the string to AAA - BBB - CCC. Since he knows the order in which they will be appearing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @CodeBunny he says '... or other random values'. I'm not sure if he is sure about the order. Of course, if it will be exactly in specified order there is no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to replace the same pattern with something else every time you could consider using `preg_replace_callback()`. At every match, a function is executed and you can return a different string at every invocation:

```
$s = '{pattern} test {pattern} how r u {pattern}';

// this gets called at every match    
function replace_pattern($match)
{
    // list of replacement strings $a and a looping counter $i
    static $a = array('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
    static $i = 0;

    // return current replacement string and increase counter
    return $a[$i++ % count($a)];
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/{pattern}/', 'replace_pattern', $s);
```

This solution cycles the replacement strings, so it will replace like AAA, BBB, CCC, AAA (again), etc. The exact strategy you wish to adopt may be different.

The second parameter to `preg_replace_callback()` may also be a closure (>= 5.3)

Also, instead of using a regular function with `static` declarations, it might be more appropriate to use an object for state management.

Comment: Damnit! exactly what i wanted to post :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
$str = '{pattern} test {pattern} how r u pattern {pattern}';
$repl = array('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
$tok = preg_split('~(?<={)pattern(?=})~', $str);
$out = '';
for ($i=0; $i<count($tok); $i++)
   $out .= $tok[$i] . $repl[$i];
var_dump($out);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(38) "{AAA} test {BBB} how r u pattern {CCC}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array(
  'aaa', // first match
  'bbb', // second match
  'ccc'  // third match
);

$subject = '{pattern} test {pattern} how r u {pattern}';

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/\{(.*?)\}/', function($matches) use ($values) { static $i = 0; return $values[$i++];  }, $subject);

echo $replaced;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at preg_replace if you are familiar with regular expressions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern =array("{pattern1}","{pattern2}","{pattern3}");
$replace=array("aaaaa","bbbbb","ccccc");
$string="{pattern1} test {pattern2} how r u {pattern3}";
$replaceme=str_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str-replace):

```
$haystack  = "{patternA} test {patternB} how are you {patternC}";
$search_for = array("{patternA}","{patternB}","{patternC}");
$replace_with   = array("{AAA}", "{BBB}", "{CCC}");

$new_string = str_replace($search_for, $replace_with, $haystack);
```

Comment: I appreciate ur answer but in my case its not like patternA ,patternB.In my case these are same only pattern word.So how could I recognize and then replace that.like I have count pattern word with substr_count

Comment: How do you know which same word to replace with AAA or BBB or CCC?

Comment: We need to do raplace same word with any random values

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously multiple ways to achieve this but the most recommended one would be using regular expressions. They are well worth to learn but in case you don't have the time to learn it now, you can just look at a cheat sheet and make one that fits your needs for a specific task in a relatively short time.

Comment: The most recommended would be a built-in function that would work a regular expression is overkill for this use case.